# Django sometimes receives ManyToManyField lookup result from some sort of cache

Tags: django, many-to-many

**EDIT:** I have removed all "example" code and inserted only my actual code.

When I try to access a ManyToManyField with `through=` specified using the field name, the results are taken from some kind of cache - not from the database.

These are my models with unnecessary fields omitted:

```py
class Assay(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='Example assay name')
    departments = models.ManyToManyField("Department",
        through="Department_assay",
        related_query_name='department',
        related_name='assays'
    )
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Department(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='Example Department name')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Department_assay(models.Model):
    department = models.ForeignKey(Department, models.CASCADE)
    assay = models.ForeignKey(Assay, models.CASCADE)
    # And some more additional data, which is unrelated
```

Now, let's try to access some of these.

```py
>>> for o in Assay.objects.all():
...     print(o.departments.all())
...
<QuerySet [<Department: Biochemistry>]>
<QuerySet [<Department: Biochemistry>]>
<QuerySet [<Department: Biochemistry>]>
<QuerySet [<Department: Biochemistry>]>
<QuerySet [<Department: Biochemistry>]>
<QuerySet [<Department: Biochemistry>]>
>>> # So it says i have 6 Assays each having the same single Department.
>>> # Now let's try to access these using *_set attribute of the Assay.
>>> for assay in Assay.objects.all():
...     print('Assay name: ' + assay.name)
...     print('departments: ' + str([o.department for o in assay.department_assay_set.all()]))
...
Assay name: ASAT / SGOT (ASPARTATE AMINOTRANSFERASE)
departments: []
Assay name: HCV
departments: [<Department: Allergology>]
Assay name: HBA1C
departments: []
Assay name: ALAT / SGPT (ALANINE AMINOTRANSFERASE)
departments: [<Department: Genetics>]
Assay name: Hepatite C RNA quantitative
departments: []
Assay name: Hepatite C RNA qualitative
departments: []
>>> # Now it shows my actual rows in database:
>>> # 2 of 6 Assays have one different Department each, rest has no Departments at all.
>>> Assay.objects.get(name="HCV").departments.all()
<QuerySet [<Department: Biochemistry>]>
>>> # What's this?
>>> Assay.objects.get(name="HCV").department_assay_set.all()[0].department
<Department: Allergology>
>>> # And we're back to normal
```

Now, this problem is hard to reproduce. One of the possible reasons that crossed my mind, is that it messes up when you play around with editing the model, running application, then editing it back (no migrations in the middle).

Is there a possible solution so that accessing the set via `.departments` rather than via `.department_assay_set....department` no longer did it from some kind of cache?

Comment: You need to show real code. `.devices` is not iterable so your list comprehensions would give an error rather than the output you state. There is no "cache" so we need the full details of what you are *actually* doing to see what is going wrong.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I have edited the question: that was a typo. But I'l try to post my working code now